# Разбить строку, но не используя split

Tags: python, split

```
def split_(text_):
   word = []
   t = []
   for i in text_:
       if i == '':
           word.append(''.join(t))
           t = []
       elif i != '':
           t.append(i)
       if t:
           word.append(''.join(t))
   return word


a = "How are you"
print(split_(a))
```

Результат;
`['H', 'Ho', 'How', 'How ', 'How a', 'How ar', 'How are', 'How are ', 'How are y', 'How are yo', 'How are you']`
Предложение разбивается побуквенно. Может я до конца не понимаю как работает `split()`, конечно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно:

```py
def split(text, sep=' '):
    res = []
    word = ''
    for s in text:
        if s == sep:
            res.append(word)
            word = ''
        else:
            word += s
    res.append(word)
    return res
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сравниваете с пустой строкой, а надо с пробелом. Второй `if` надо вынести за цикл

```
def split_(text_):
   word = []
   t = []
   for i in text_:
       if i == ' ':
           word.append(''.join(t))
           t = []
       elif i != ' ':
           t.append(i)
   if t:
       word.append(''.join(t))
   return word


a = "How are you"
print(split_(a))
```